# Apache/PHP retornando status http padrão

Tags: php, apache, http, http-status

Estou criando uma api REST em PHP, e em determinadas situações retorno um status HTTP com a mensagem de erro específica para oque ocorreu, por exemplo, *403 Invalid Access Key* ao invés de simplesmente *403 Forbidden*.

Estou usando a função header() do php para gerar tais status, e local está funcionando perfeitamente, porém no servidor de produção aparecem as mensagens de status padrão. Por exemplo: onde deveria retornar *403 Invalid Access Key*, ele retorna o nada descritivo *403 Forbidden*.

Oque poderia estar causando isso? Pesquisei muito e não encontrei nada sobre o assunto.

Local: Apache 2.4.9 PHP 5.5.12

Produção: Apache 2.2.29 PHP 5.4.37

Comment: posso lher uma sugestão, as mensagens de erro e os numeros são padronizados, não somente para um servidor ou para um navegador, mas todas ferramentas que usam HTTP de alguma forma, mudar a mensagem de erro é o mesmo que despadronizar fazendo com que a lógica se perca, o melhor seria passar a mensagem customizada no BODY, por exemplo um JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Pelo visto, de alguma forma, o proxy (squid) está "padronizando" os cabeçalhos HTTP. Verifiquei isso usando clientes REST como [Hurl](https://www.hurl.it/) e [APIgee](https://apigee.com/console/others), que fazem as requisições de seus próprios servidores e não do cliente, ou seja, não passa pelo proxy. Assim, nesses clientes, o status retornou como deveria.

Não há nada que eu possa fazer sobre isso no momento, então esta não é uma resposta de "solução", mas fica a dica para quem quer que venha a precisar.